# Randomly appearing green dot

Tags: iphone, camera

Sometimes I turn on my phone. Even though I am not using the camera, a green dot appears in the upper right, indicating that the camera is being used. What is the reason of this ? Is it normal or is someone watching me? Spyware etc (Also my phone gets very hot)

Comment: What is your iPhone’s exact model and which iOS is installed on it?

Comment: Iphone 12 pro and iOS 16.6

Comment: Outside the times you use the phone’s camera yourself, does the green light come on only right after you turn on your iPhone or randomly anytime as long as the phone is on? For how long does the green light remain on in such cases? Do you do anything to turn the light off or does it turn off by itself?

Comment: While opening my phone. And sometimes when my phone is on. It is on for a few seconds and the green light turns off by itself. And when I swipe up to check it out. It says (Camera, recently) I hope this is just a bug, glitch etc. I don't want to be hacked

Answer (score 1):

Control Center will show what app is using the camera while the green dot is shown, as well as shortly after the green dot disappears (suffixed with ‘recently’) to give you time to check.

The camera can be activated from the lock screen by swiping right-to-left. The lock screen doesn’t need to be moved all the way until the camera app is visible for the camera itself to be activated. It’s possible to do this accidentally while unlocking iPhone.

Comment: Thanks for info. I hope it is not hacking. I have read the articles of other users who have experienced this issue on the Internet.